# Getting a reference to the parent IFRAME

Tags: javascript, css, dom, iframe

Say I have a reference to a document object, which is contained inside an IFRAME. How do  I get a reference to the container IFRAME? .parentNode and .ownerDocument both return null.

Please note that no context information is available (e.g. solutions like 'window.xxx' will not work) - all that's available is a reference to the document object.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "reference to a document object"? Which is the container IFRAME? Please clarify and maybe show some code

Comment: I have the reference to an HTMLDocument scripting object (in Firefox scripting environment), and no reference to its container IFrame.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A document is not directly connected to its parent document. You do need a reference to `window` in order to pick up the `parent`.

The DOM Level 2 Views property [`document.defaultView`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Views/views.html#Views-DocumentView) will give you the `window` in most modern web browsers, but in IE you have to use the non-standard [`document.parentWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534331%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) instead. (Some older or more obscure browsers don't implement either of these properties, in which case you're stuck.)

That'll give you the `window` of the parent document. If you want to get the `<iframe>` that holds your document, you'll have to iterate through all the iframes on the page and check whether the contained document is yourself.

Again, the method to get from an iframe element back to the child is gratuitously different in IE (`iframe.contentWindow` giving you the `window`) vs the DOM standard and everyone else (`iframe.contentDocument` giving you the `document`).

So, something like:

```
function getFrameForDocument(document) {
    var w= document.defaultView || document.parentWindow;
    var frames= w.parent.document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
    for (var i= frames.length; i-->0;) {
        var frame= frames[i];
        try {
            var d= frame.contentDocument || frame.contentWindow.document;
            if (d===document)
                return frame;
        } catch(e) {}
    }
}
```

(The `try...` is to avoid crashing the loop out when a document access fails due to another iframe being on a different domain, causing a Same Origin Policy error.)

Answer (score 1):

I use this:

```
function get_container_iframe()
         {var rtn_iframe=null;
          var iframes=window.parent.document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
          for (var i=0; i<iframes.length; ++i)
              {try
                   {var d=iframes[i].contentDocument || iframes[i].contentWindow.document || iframes[i].document; //ie | firefox etc | ie5
                    if (d===window.document)
                       {rtn_iframe=iframes[i];
                        break;
                       }
                   }
               catch(e) {}
              }
          return rtn_iframe;
         }
```